# Woocommerce - Add a product to cart programmatically via JS or PHP

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am using the Woocommerce plugin to facilitate a small e-commerce part of a site and need to add products to its cart via some call or function rather than using its own 'add-to-cart' buttons.

By this I basically mean send Woocommerce a SKU and quantity for example and have the cart update.

```
sendToCart('123456', 55);
```

etc

I've looked through the documentation and can't seem to find a reference to this sort of thing. Can anyone suggest how I might achieve this?

Comment: Close-voted as **too localized**. Have you tried WooThemes support?

Comment: @Chip Bennett I have yes, they charge $125 dollars just to join unfortunately. This comes under the bracket of both Wordpress and Woocommerce - itself a valid tag here, so is surely valid? Unless I am misunderstanding 'too localized'?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with **WordPress** specifically. It involves only the WooCommerce Plugin itself - Plugin functionality and custom Plugin functions/code. I could have close-voted as **off-topic**, but I usually use **too localized** for questions about commercial products, or products that have commercial support options.

Comment: @ChipBennett Woocommerce is only for Wordpress so seems odd to catagorise as nothing to do with wordpress. How would one use the Woocommerce tag if not to post a question about Woocommerce? At any rate I have found the answer which I shall post now in case anyone else has the same problem.

Comment: I didn't say *WooCommerce* had nothing to do with WordPress, but rather that **your specific question** has nothing to do with WordPress. The difference between the two is critical.

Comment: @ChipBennett Well I'd have to disagree. Why is there a Woocommerce tag if not to ask questions about Woocommerce. Woocommerce is not a standalone in any way so anything relating to Woocommerce is pertinent to Wordpress. But that's just my opinion of course.

Comment: Please read [the FAQ regarding scope of questions for WPSE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#questions): "*Note that we **do not handle** questions... **not specific to WordPress** (even if they happen in its context).*" Just because WooCommerce runs in the context of WordPress does not mean that every single question about WooCommerce is in-scope for WPSE.

Comment: Please post answers as **answers**, not as *edits to the original question*. [**Please read the FAQ**](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq) so that you understand how StackExchange Q & A sites work.

Comment: I have to wait 8 hours as rep<10 so will then.

Comment: @GHarping Thank you for asking this question, even though you got a bunch of crap for it. :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

OK so here's how I solved it in the end. A quick and dirty example, uses JQuery.

```
<a id="buy" href="#">Buy this!</a>
    <script>    
       $('#buy').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          addToCart(19);
          return false;
       });    

       function addToCart(p_id) {
          $.get('/wp/?post_type=product&add-to-cart=' + p_id, function() {
             // call back
          });
       }
    </script>
```

This just makes an AJAX GET request to the cart url

```
/wp/?post_type=product&add-to-cart=[PRODUCT_ID]
```

Comment: this is not working anymore (wc v2.1.12). found a solution and shared it [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/86967/woocommerce-add-variation-product-to-cart-from-custom-link/159390#159390)

Comment: I've used this tutorial which helped me achieve what I needed:
https://wpharvest.com/add-product-to-cart-programmatically-in-woocommerce/

Answer (score 37):

In PHP I managed to do it this way:

```
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id);
```

The method is in woocommerce/classes/class-wc-cart.php:

```
    /**
     * Add a product to the cart.
     *
     * @param string $product_id contains the id of the product to add to the cart
     * @param string $quantity contains the quantity of the item to add
     * @param int $variation_id
     * @param array $variation attribute values
     * @param array $cart_item_data extra cart item data we want to pass into the item
     * @return bool
     */
    public function add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity = 1, $variation_id = '', $variation = '', $cart_item_data = array() ) {
```

Comment: How could I call that method via ajax?

Comment: @Stratboy by using the recommended way of adding AJAX functions in Wordpress: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins - basically you just insert the 3 lines from the answer in the first php example from the wordpress codex.