# How to add to cart via AJAX Woocommerce

Tags: ajax, plugins

I have been searching for a while, this. I want to add an item via AJAX. When you add an item to a cart in Woocommerce the page reloads with the GET parameter `add-to-cart="The current product ID"`.

I want to do it via AJAX. In the admin area is a checkbox to enable that featured that is labeled "Enable AJAX buttons to add to cart on the product list"

But it doesn't do anything, it stills reloading the page.

Comment: "Enable AJAX buttons to add to cart on the product list" g.translate

Comment: @david as I wrote, I checked the enable AJAX button, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: This was no advice from my site, I was just translating your Spanish sentence :)

Comment: @jepser did you ever find out the answer to this question? Its been bugging me aswell.

Comment: Nope I have been waiting for someone that explain me this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

are we talking about the single product view or the product archive pages (shop,categories)?

because the text beside the checkbox/option states, roughly translated:

*»activate ajax-checkout-button on product archive pages«*

and on all the installations i did so for, that is the way its working - ajax checkout on the archives, but not on the single view.

the latter you have to implement yourself or maybe you find a free plugin for that.

---

*Follow up:*

A basic example on how to use AJAX for the »add-to-cart«-functionality of woocommerce can be found here: 
[Woocommerce - Add a product to cart programmatically via JS or PHP](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53516/22534).

Comment: This is correct. The ajax add to cart option is only for product archives. To do add-to-cart via ajax on the single product page, you'd need to set up a jQuery click event and do the ajax call there.