# Woocommerce Add Variation Product to Cart from custom link

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to add a variation product to my cart directly through a link. I am setting the variation_id with the query string. As far as I can tell I am sending the data the exact same way as the default variation product form does.

Here's the code inside of my single-product page:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>&variation_id=262" class="rounded-rect-button add-to-cart">Add to Cart</a>
```

Conversely, the simple product works fine. I have set prices to my product variations in the admin. Not sure why it's not as simple as sending the data through. Any help would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured this one out. I was missing a couple parameters needed to add a variable product to my cart. The missing params are the `variation_id` and the attribute type that the `variation_id` is referring to. The variation id can be found in the admin > woocomerce > products and under the variations tab next to the product variation you have created.

The attribute param is formed from the prefix `attribute_` and then the sanitized attribute name. For example, my attribute is called Stock Colors, so my attribute type param is attribute_stock-colors. From what i can tell, you just set `attribute_stock-colors=1` because the add to cart method just check to see if it exists.

Here's a simple example of a link that adds a product to my cart with variation id 261 of stock colors:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>&variation_id=261&attribute_stock-colors=1">Add to Cart</a>
```

To use this in a real situation you would need to set the attribute type and variation id dynamically from the options the user picked in a drop down or something like that (unless every product has the same variation, which would basically make it a simpel product).

Answer (score 13):

i currently work on a woocommerce v2.1.12 shop and it seems they chaged that behavior.

my ajax url to add items to the cart has to look like this:

```
?add-to-cart=[PRODUCT-ID]&variation_id=[VARIATION-ID]&attribute_[ATTRIBUTE-NAME]=[ATTRIBUTE-SLUG]&attribute_[ATTRIBUTE-NAME]=[ATTRIBUTE-SLUG]
```

example:

```
http://example.com/store/category/product/?add-to-cart=239&variation_id=240&attribute_pa_size=48-2&attribute_pa_color=gold
```

this adds a specific product to the cart and also sets the variation attributes in the cart.
you can even set the quantity by simply adding `&quantity=[VALUE]`

in the end this comes in handy since all these values are set inside the submit form / select fields, you just have to look those up..

Comment: Quick note - inspect the variations select field for the proper attribute name. It typically uses hyphens, so you get: &attribute_my-attribute-name=value