# Consolidate 'add-to-cart' buttons into one 'add-all-to-cart' button

Tags: customization, themes, plugins

What I am trying to achieve is to have one add-to-cart button that will add the selected quantity of multiple products, featured on the catalog page, into the basket.

Here is an image of what I aim to have:

[image: example]

I've found the code that outputs the existing button has the following code:

```
echo apply_filters(
    'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
    sprintf('<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s button product_type_%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( $link['url'] ),
        esc_attr( $product->id ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( $link['class'] ),
        esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
        esc_html( $link['label'] ) ),
    $product,
    $link
);
```

I'm aware that there could be a way to use jQuery to submit each individual form, via a loop, at once but due to my limited knowledge, I don't think I could implement it.

Alternatively, if there is a way to have a custom button that can submit multiple forms for each product and its corresponding quantity that may make things easier in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the Grouped product type is for what you want.

You can create a Grouped product and then add child products to it. A grouped product (with the child products) can be added by one click.

See [WooThemes docs](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/managing-products/#section-2).

**Edit:**

If it's not what you're looking for, try to search for submitting multiple forms with jQuery (maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036917/submit-multiple-forms-one-by-one-using-jquery)), and have a look at this question about AJAX add-to-cart:

[Woocommerce - Add a product to cart programmatically via JS or PHP](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53280/woocommerce-add-a-product-to-cart-programmatically-via-js-or-php)

Comment: Unfortunately, this has not solved my original question, as it simply provides an alternative method of listing products.
If I am going wrong somewhere, let me know.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, updated my answer, maybe you can use one of the links.

Answer (score 1):

The following is not a solution to just insert into a regular WooCommerce catalog page. However, this would easily serve as a basis for someone trying to achieve that.

**Background:** I'm building an Angular/JS app to load on the archive-product page, which will handle everything including the cart until a user is ready to proceed to checkout... at which point I needed an Ajax call to dump the entire cart in one run into the "real" WooCommerce cart and crack on with checkout.
I tried to be thorough and make it almost ready to work with regular WooCommerce pages but I've never written PHP before. Additionally,
I'm not falling back for any non-JS users and have no individual product pages.

There are a few plugins out there that claim to do this, but I've inspected them and all "add to cart" via Ajax, one product at a time. My feeling was, this is *BS* and very inefficient for large numbers of items.

My solution was to extend the WC_AJAX class and add a new method to it to handle multiple products & quantities, all in one call.

I followed this [excellent tutorial](http://patzmatias.github.io/blog/2016/05/24/how-to-add-a-custom-ajax-url-to-woocommerce-ajax-urls/)
and implemented my own method similarly.

I extended the class as per the noted tutorial and added a method `multiple_add_to_cart` as below (if you don't use ChromePhp for debugging, just delete those lines):

```
public static function multiple_add_to_cart() {
    ob_start();
    /*
    *Decode json to a post varioable
    */
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && empty($_POST)) {
        $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        $products = $_POST['products'];
    } else {
        $products = $POST['products'];
    }
    $errors = false;
    $errorArr = array();
    /* for each product, json decode data & deal with it as per original add to cart function */
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $prod = json_decode($product);
        ChromePhp::log("Prod: " . $prod->id . " - Qty: " . $prod->qty);
        $product_id        = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint( $prod->id ) );
        $quantity          = empty( $prod->qty ) ? 1 : wc_stock_amount( $prod->qty );
        $passed_validation = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity );
        $product_status    = get_post_status( $product_id );

        if ( $passed_validation && false !== WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity ) && 'publish' === $product_status ) {

        ChromePhp::log("Added!");
        do_action( 'woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product_id );

        } else {
            /*
            * If product had errors add it to error array for output at end - to inspect later with js.
            */
            $errors = true;
            $object = (object) ['id' => $product_id, 'valid' => $passed_validation, 'Status' => $product_status];
            $errorArray[] = $object;
        }
    }

    if($errors) {
        ChromePhp::log("There were errors!" . $errorArray);
        wp_send_json( $errorArray );
    } else {
        // Return fragments if you like but no use to me.
        //self::get_refreshed_fragments();

        $suc = array(
            'error'  => false,
        );
        wp_send_json( $suc );
    }

    die();
}
```

I then call the service within Angular/JS with an Ajax call thus:

```
var products = [];
        var p1 = {};
        p1['id'] = '6147';
        p1['qty'] = '3';
        products.push(JSON.stringify(p1));

        var p2 = {};
        p2['id'] = '6147';
        p2['qty'] = '4';
        products.push(JSON.stringify(p2));

        var p3 = {};
        p3['id'] = '6157'; // !Doesnt exist !
        p3['qty'] = '3';
        products.push(JSON.stringify(p3));

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: sitePath,
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            params: {
                'wc-ajax': 'multiple_add_to_cart'
            },
            data: {
                'products': products
            }
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
        }, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
        });
```

I expect, I'll continue to add further functions to the Ajax class to handle anything else I want to communicate with WooCommerce from within my app...
gimme a shout if you want a copy of the entire class.

If any PHP gurus out there can help clean up my code a bit, make it more universal, or help port this to a functioning "plugin" for use on any WooCommerce site, that would be an awesome learn for me.

Comment: Nice one for the edit Gabriel! I realise i have to improve on being concise! x